# undefined is not an object react navigation from doc

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this code that come directly from the doc of react navigation link here.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to Jane's profile"
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
      }
    />
  );
};
const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  return <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile</Text>;
};


const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <HomeScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and when i click on the button i have this error : undefined is not an object. can you help me found what's wrong ?
That just to test at the end i want different page in my app and navigate into,
i don't understant why all the different page is on the same file ...
Thank you,
have good coding day

Answer (score 0):

The Reason Behind this is you are used **HomeScreen** component inside **App** component.You Have to use **MyStack** component inside the App component.

then you get error about **NavigationContainer** you have to use **NavigationContainer** one time not in nested.Please remove **NavigationContainer** from App component or MyStack component.

also Add ..

```
import{Text} from 'react-native';
```

**congratulations** Your Programm run perfectly.

I Changed small things in your code please copy and then try it will work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button,Text} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to Jane's profile"
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
      }
    />
  );
};

const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  return <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile</Text>;
};


const App = () => {
  return ( 
      <MyStack />
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Happy Coding**